# Efficient Permutation of a Sorted List with Repetitions

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, permutation, repeat

I have a list of names assigned to ranks, often with ranks duplicated. I want to generate all permutations of the list with keeping the ranks in sorted order. For example:

```
[Sam(17), Harry(17), Bob(5), Sally(5)]
```

would generate

```
Sam(17), Harry(17), Bob(5), Sally(5)

Sam(17), Harry(17), Sally(5), Bob(5)

Harry(17), Sam(17), Bob(5), Sally(5)

Harry(17), Sam(17), Sally(5), Bob(5)
```

Essentially, for every distinct group of ranks, there are n! combinations. In this case it would be 2! * 2!. I'm having trouble finding an efficient way to do permutations for a list with 34 names across 8 ranks.

I'm running out of memory trying to find 2! * 2! * 4! * 2! * 2! *8! * 4! * 10! different lists.

Is there any efficient way to generate this list? How much memory would python need?

Comment: You should look into `itertools`; it seems like you want to create each group, then do a `product` of their `permutations`. If you do it with iterators, you don't have to have the whole list in memory at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) solution using `groupby`, `permutations` and `product`. As it mostly uses generators it should be not too heavy on memory. If you don't need the result as a list, but for example just want to iterate over it memory requirements should in fact be rather modest.

If you need the list, you'll need the memory for the list but not much more.

But I'm afraid with your numbers the final list alone will just be too large to fit in memory. And the loop will take forever.

```
>> import itertools, operator
>>> 
>>> data = *zip('Peter Paul Mary Jack Jill'.split(), (17, 17, 17, 4, 4)),
>>> data
(('Peter', 17), ('Paul', 17), ('Mary', 17), ('Jack', 4), ('Jill', 4))
>>> 
# group by rank
>>> groups = itertools.groupby(data, operator.itemgetter(1))
# extract the groups and generate all permutations of each of them
>>> permutations = map(itertools.permutations, map(operator.itemgetter(1), groups))
# form the cartesian product of the permutations, flatten out excess nesting
# convert inner generators to lists
>>> result = map(list, map(itertools.chain.from_iterable, itertools.product(*permutations)))
>>> for i in result:
...     print(i)
... 
[('Peter', 17), ('Paul', 17), ('Mary', 17), ('Jack', 4), ('Jill', 4)]
[('Peter', 17), ('Paul', 17), ('Mary', 17), ('Jill', 4), ('Jack', 4)]
[('Peter', 17), ('Mary', 17), ('Paul', 17), ('Jack', 4), ('Jill', 4)]
[('Peter', 17), ('Mary', 17), ('Paul', 17), ('Jill', 4), ('Jack', 4)]
[('Paul', 17), ('Peter', 17), ('Mary', 17), ('Jack', 4), ('Jill', 4)]
[('Paul', 17), ('Peter', 17), ('Mary', 17), ('Jill', 4), ('Jack', 4)]
[('Paul', 17), ('Mary', 17), ('Peter', 17), ('Jack', 4), ('Jill', 4)]
[('Paul', 17), ('Mary', 17), ('Peter', 17), ('Jill', 4), ('Jack', 4)]
[('Mary', 17), ('Peter', 17), ('Paul', 17), ('Jack', 4), ('Jill', 4)]
[('Mary', 17), ('Peter', 17), ('Paul', 17), ('Jill', 4), ('Jack', 4)]
[('Mary', 17), ('Paul', 17), ('Peter', 17), ('Jack', 4), ('Jill', 4)]
[('Mary', 17), ('Paul', 17), ('Peter', 17), ('Jill', 4), ('Jack', 4)]
```

Comment: It might be worth noting that the two `operator.itemgetter(1)`s are in quite different roles. Assigning names might help, e.g. using `get_rank = operator.itemgetter(1)` for the first usage and doing something more like `group for rank, group in groupby(data, get_rank)` for the second. I also thought the syntax for creating the initial dataset was an unnecessary detail, especially given that it's not actually even the OP's structure; YMMV.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Fair enough. It seems some of your edits got lost due to the both of us editing simultaneously.

Comment: No worries, I put the (IMO) most important bit back.

Comment: @Paul, with the final iterator object, can I still access and manipulate individual elements specifically? This sounds a little crazy, but I wanted to use an individual element as an intermediary into a function that would generate a score. The permutation with the lowest score is the optimal. Is that possible?

Comment: @S.Avenci You can loop over them but you can't access them out of order. But what you describe is easy. If `f` is your score function taking a permutation as its single argument and returning a number you could simply do `min(result, key=f)` to obtain the optimal permutation. One gotcha if you are new to generators: You can only use them once, after that they are used up.

Comment: @PaulPanzer, I posted a follow up question in a new post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48890902/run-through-large-generator-iterable-on-gpu . What is the upper limit of permutations that can be feasibly done in python?